# Deployed Heroku app works great on desktop, but only blank screen on mobile

Tags: reactjs, heroku, redux, deployment

my deployed heroku app is working fine on desktop, but when i go to the app url on mobile i just get a blank screen. Anyone have any experience with this issue? My app is 
[here](https://goals-against-united-114.herokuapp.com) if anyone wants to inspect it.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: you can reproduce issue in safari, not only mobile [error](https://ibb.co/qsvSpCY) Looks like is something related to redux

Comment: Thank you! This lead to me to a fix. In my case, it was an issue with Redux dev tools. If anyone else out there has this issue, [here is the fix i used.](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/2033)